# Using data returned from forms in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Sorry for being a little new. My goal is to use the data collected from a user form to output a graph. The user inputs an initial 'price' then submits this number, it then goes into my formulas written in python and then django should display a chart in the same HTML file. I'm currently stuck on how to use data from 'POST'.

For example, if I'd like to take the cleaned_data from 'strike1' and multiply it by 4, then display it on the webpage, how would I go about doing that?

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import DataForm

# Create your views here.

def data(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DataForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            strike1 = form.cleaned_data['strike1']
            strike2 = form.cleaned_data['strike2']
            strike3 = form.cleaned_data['strike3']
            strike4 = form.cleaned_data['strike4']
            strategy = form.cleaned_data['strategy']
            price = range(0,50)
            premium1 = form.cleaned_data['premium1']
            premium2 = form.cleaned_data['premium2']
            premium3 = form.cleaned_data['premium3']
            premium4 = form.cleaned_data['premium4']
            contracts = form.cleaned_data['contracts']



    form = DataForm()
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms


class DataForm(forms.Form):

    strategy = forms.ChoiceField(
            choices=[('Long Call', 'Long Call'), ('Long Put', 'Long Put'), ('Short Call', 'Short Call',),
                     ('Short Put', 'Short Put'), ('Bull Call Spread', 'Bull Call Spread'),
                     ('Bear Put Spread', 'Bear Put Spread'), ('Straddle', 'Straddle'),
                     ('Butterfly Spread', 'Butterfly Spread'),
                     ('Box Spread', 'Box Spread'), ('Iron Condor', 'Iron Condor')])
    strike1 = forms.FloatField()
    strike2 = forms.FloatField()
    strike3 = forms.FloatField()
    strike4 = forms.FloatField()

    premium1 = forms.FloatField()
    premium2 = forms.FloatField()
    premium3 = forms.FloatField()
    premium4 = forms.FloatField()

    contracts = forms.IntegerField()
```

form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="'post">

        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form }}

        <button type="Submit">Generate</button>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the cleanest way to do it, is to build up a new "content" and render a new page in the POST processing section. For example:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import DataForm

# Create your views here.

def data(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DataForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            # ... do you processing as it

            return render(request, 'output.html', {'data': whatever}) 

    form = DataForm()
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

You could also just let it call through to the original `render` function, but you'll need to include whatever information you want in the context like {"form: form} already is.

Comment: How would you do it through the original render? I keep getting not defined. Thanks

Comment: Which variable or function does it say is defined?

Answer (score 0):

U need to create 2 views for using data.(basicly)
One for form, one for your formulas. 
in urls.py

```
path('formpage/', views.formpage, name='form_view'),

path('result/', views.result, name='MY_calculator'),
```

in views.py

```
def formpage(request):
    return render(request, '-----Template-----',)

def result(request):
    x=request.GET.get('xval')
    y=request.GET.get('yval')
    result=x+y
    return render(request, '-----Result Template----', {'result': result})
```

and form action for template. ("" instead of)

```
<form action="{% url 'MY_calculator' %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set [`initial values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#initial) to your form and render them to the same template within the same URL.

Here is an example:

```
def data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DataForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            strike1 = form.cleaned_data['strike1'] * 2
            strike2 = form.cleaned_data['strike2'] * 3
            # Set initials
            # strike1 & strike2 new values will be rendered as default values
            # in your form
            form = DataForm(initial={'strike1': strike1, 'strike2': strike2})
            return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})

    form = DataForm()
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

Also, you must pay attention, in your template HTML you wrote `"'post"` instead of `"post"`.